# Graphviz: Distinct colors for xlabel and nodelabel

Tags: graphviz

Is it possible to have distinct font colors for xlabel and node label in Graphviz?

```
digraph {
    "complete" [xlabel="complete", label="complete", fontcolor=red];
}
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273).

Comment: Your question is somewhat ambiguous, but Graphviz does not support themes directly.  Do you want compile-time theme (color change) or runtime theme?

Comment: there is no theme. edited question adds clarity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only way I know of is a bit of a kludge.  Use html labels for the label or xlabel:

```
digraph {
    "complete" [xlabel=<<font color="green">Xcomplete</font>>
        label="complete", fontcolor=red];
}
```

produces this:
[image]